# How to send send images on email using email js (Flutter) (Hive) (EmailJs)

Tags: android, flutter, email, email-attachments, flutter-hive

Can anyone show me how to send images by email using EmailJs and Hive?
I stored my images on a Hive, all as Bytes (List). How can I attach those images and send them by email? I'm not using the 'assets folder', all photos were taken by the phone (Android)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of attachments
1 is

Static Attachments
The Static Attachments will be automatically sent with every email sent for your current template. For example, a company logo.

2 is

Dynamic Attachments
The Dynamic Attachments are used to send attachments from your JavaScript code. Can be optional.

both come with limit and there is subscription for this feature

Comment: Thanks for the info! But how ? How I code this?

Comment: Here is a guide for you 
https://www.emailjs.com/docs/user-guide/file-attachments/